# war file does not contain version number

Tags: java, maven

I have these settings in my pom and try to run maven goals (mostly `mvn clean install`). I expect it to create a `war` file which looks like, `project-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`. but it always creates `project.war`. How can I create a war file which contains the version info in the file name?

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxxxxxx</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>war-common-pom</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.pom</groupId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </parent>
   

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.3.18.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName></finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <warSourceExcludes>node_modules/**</warSourceExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v12.16.1</nodeVersion>
                    <npmVersion>6.13.4</npmVersion>
                    <workingDirectory>src/main/webapp/frontend</workingDirectory>

                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Install node and npm locally to the project</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>Build frontend</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Copy frontend build to target</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/resources</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/frontend/build</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Could you add the complete POM? Does it contain a `<finalname>` entry?

Comment: Remove the manual binding to the life cycle or the trying to decouple the plugin from the lifecycle. Apart from that upgrade your maven-war-plugin to the most recent one.. The other question: Where do you expect to have the mentioned naming? in your `target` directory or in your local repository?

Comment: @khmarbaise in side of `target` directory.

Comment: @JFMeier I did have `<finalName>`. and I removed, but it still generates without version information.

Comment: please make an example project on github ....

Comment: @khmarbaise I added whole pom.xml. Do you need to see my folder structure?

Comment: Remove the `<finalName></finalName>` completely also why using such ancient version of maven-war-plugin? Are there good reason why you are using such old spring versions? 4.X ? If I correctly remember 5.X is long time available.. ? Is there a reason to use spring instead of Spring boot? And very important: What does the parent does?

Comment: @khmarbaise I completely removed it. The reasons are, it is work.... and `<parent>` holds the top project, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the entire `finalName` construct, not just the value.  In other words, instead of:

```
<build>
    <finalName></finalName>
    <plugins>
```

have:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
```

Comment: I think they mention in the comments that they tried this and it didn’t work.

Comment: @Woodchuck - It wasn't clear exactly what was tried.  Since the example XML shows a missing value, I guessed that the author removed the value and not the entire tag.  (I don't know what <finalName></finalName> would represent otherwise - a nameless war file?)